# CropZoom not working with IIS 7.5 but works with IIS 7.5 Express

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, crop, iis-express

This is rather strange to me.  I could generalize this question to be javascript/webserver specific but i'll give you the details.

I've integrated image cropping into my asp.net webforms application.  this is the image cropper i am using:

http://www.gastonrobledo.com.ar/cropzoom/index.html

it works fine in VS development server & IIS express 7.5, but as soon as i deploy it to IIS 7.5 full version on Windows 2008 R2, the cropper functionality stops working in IE8 & IE9 browsers only!  Everything else in my web app works fine.  This is really strange as I am using all the default settings in both IIS Express and IIS full version (i've switched the authentication mode to 'Windows' in both)

I'm not sure were to start looking as far as IIS 7.5 settings relating to javascript and or css files.  Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?  I have checked all the trivial stuff (making sure im deploying all the files, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Probably this tool uses some server side code/script which requires higher privileges.
IIS Express (and also VS development server) run as current logged on user, whereas IIS runs with app pool identity. Try running IIS with an app pool that has higher privileges.

Comment: What privileges are "higher" than the ones IIS has by default? And how do you change an app pool's privileges?